# Raspberry Pi Bluetooth Transmitter

Tags: bluetooth

Is it possible to use the raspberry pi to transmit USB signal to another computer?

I am wanting to plug a wired keyboard into a usb hub and transmit the signal to another computer to essentially make the keyboard wireless. If a raspberry pi wouldn't work in this situation does anyone have any suggestions as to how I could accomplish this?

Thanks for your replies

Answer (score 1):

The way this is done in several existing [projects](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/327270/emulate-a-bluetooth-mouse) out there is to emulate a Bluetooth HID on a computer. The one I know which is open-source is [hidclient](https://github.com/benizi/hidclient). The setup is far from seamless though. I've used [Master Control](https://pyra-handheld.com/boards/threads/wip-master-control-testers-needed.72081/) in the past, and it was much more user-friendly, but AFAIK it's not open-source.

It's also possible to transmit raw [USB packets over a TCP/IP](http://usbip.sourceforge.net/) network (WiFi, if you want it wireless). Again, the setup will be more complex as just pairing a BT keyboard/mouse. You need to set up the network, tell the PC which IP address to use, etc.